# Is it possible to suppress the GUI for lasboundary within a python script?

Tags: python, lastools, subprocess

This is the lasboundary call:
Lasboundary = [lasboundary,
'-i', LBin,
'-odir', ClipFolder,
'-labels',
'-overview',
'-oshp'
]
pcs = subprocess.run(lasboundary, check=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

It seems to not be accepting my flags as the GUI opens without any of the supplied (inputs/odir/overview etc).